Map value to set of indexes
Assuming you have a Map and Set type, you can construct this structure.
type IndexMap<T> = Map<T, Set<int>>

This would be a Map (or dictionary) where the key is the generic type T and the value is a set of integers.
If you had an array like
[1,2,2,3,3,3]

it could be stored just the same in this structure like such
IndexMap<int> = {
1: {0}, // value 1 at index 0
2: {1,2}, // value 2 at indexes 1, 2
3: {3,4,5} // etc.
}

Using sets of unique integers as indexes ensures there is no duplicates as it is not possible to store 2 values at 1 index.
Using this "IndexMap" structure allows you to use arrays without using arrays. It might involve more memory but the accessing of values should be as quick as maps are.
Has this been thought of before? Would it have any real advantages?


"Has this been thought of before?"

Sure, we combine standard containers and lookup data types all the time, whenever we need them.
In this case, one gets a structure where it is quick to find out the indexes of a given value. This comes for the price of making it slower to retrieve the value at a given index.
If one needs both, fast retrieval in both directions, one can create an array plus an index map, storing the same information twice, redundantly. This, however, comes for the price of requiring twice as memory and slower updates in case the container content changes.

Would it have any real advantages?

This is a nonsensical question. You have a solution looking for a problem. To assess whether some solution has "advantages", you need to state

for solving which problem?

when compared to which other solution to the problem?


Speaking about myself - I found it always more effective to start with a problem  first and then look for solution, and not the other way round. But YMMV.


Using sets of unique integers as indexes ensures there is no duplicates

No it doesn't.
IndexMap<int> = {
1: {0,1,2,3,4,5}, // Uh oh
2: {1,2},
3: {3,4,5}
}

